# how do Sencha, phonegap, or corona really work under the hood?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, extjs, coronasdk

how do these platforms allow one to write a single code for multiple mobile phone platforms?

what kind of magic is going on that allows simple javascript to be used in Sencha to produce multi platform app? I am highly skeptical of all the solutions out there. Especially when they are commercial and no one really explains well what goes on under the hood.

Comment: When you examined the source code for Apache Cordova/PhoneGap, and when you visited their Web sites, and when you read the available books on PhoneGap, and when you searched the Internet for articles and blog posts on these technologies, what did you find?

Comment: I was hoping you would share that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you write your code using HTML/CSS/JS. PhoneGap now Corona implements the native code that bridges your code (HTML/CSS/JS) with the native code allowing you to call native functionality.

Comment: some more details on how it bridges would be nice

Comment: For Android see: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript

Answer (score 0):

It isn't simple Javascript. JS has to be written separately for each platform for each of the platforms' features. It's a complex undertaking. If you are not using any of the phone's features, then that code goes unused, and your HTML/CSS/JS is shown in that device's web view.